# Commenting python lines that are code, which style to use?

Tags: python, comments, pep8

Let's say I have the following python snippet:

```
if True:
    print("a")
    print("b")
    print("c")
else:
    print("d")
```

I am making an editor which has a feature to toggle comment on selected lines, but I cannot decide whether to use

```
# if True:
    # print("a")
    # print("b")
    # print("c")
# else:
    # print("d")
```

or

```
# if True:
#     print("a")
#     print("b")
#     print("c")
# else:
#     print("d")
```

I am more inclined to use the second one, as it will also make is easier for opening the file in another editor that has column-wise editing capabilities.

Whereas the first one makes it more readable when commenting parts in the middle:

```
if True:
    print("a")
    # print("b")
    print("c")
else:
    print("d")
```

I was wondering if there is anything like pep8 for this case as well. I couldn't find anything there or on google.

Thanks!

Comment: I would say delete the lines completely. You'll probably never need them anyway. If you really plan to use them for _something_, put them in a condition (`if SOMETHING_ACTIVE:`) and set `SOMETHING_ACTIVE = False`.

Comment: @zvone the example code is irrelevant. The OP stated: "I am making an editor which has a feature to toggle comment on selected lines"

Comment: @GordonAitchJay Ah, I missed that point. In that case I have no comment :)

Comment: I'd argue that this is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per pep8 there is guide for multi-line comments but only for `doc string` and other useful information for code following the comments.

However as per your question to decide which is better to use to comment the `python code`, there is my thumb rule that it should comment based on most outer indentation line in selected code lines.

So your second way is what I will suggest.

For single line comment there is no need to decide between the indentation of other line of code.